# Python, sort a dictionary of orderedDicts by their sum's value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following Dictionary:

```py
pprint(cls.bags)

{'ground system bag': {'Ground System Bag': 8.0, 'Tablet': 9.65},
 'planes bag': {'Baznat': 0.72,
                'Bungee': 1.26,
                'Full Bandolera ': 3.76,
                'hammer': 1.28,
                'planes bag': 8.5},
 'pods bag': {'Pod': 1.74, 'optic': 0.86, 'pods bag': 8.72, 'thermal': 1.2}}
```

I want to sort the nested dictionaries by the sum of their values.

meaning, the result should be:

```py
for item in cls.bags.values():
    pprint(sum(item.values()))
```

output:

```
15.52
12.52
17.65
```

when the dict is sorted it should be:

```
17.65
15.52
12.52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

x = {
    'ground system bag': {
        'Ground System Bag': 8.0, 
        'Tablet': 9.65
    },
    'planes bag': {
        'Baznat': 0.72,
        'Bungee': 1.26,
        'Full Bandolera ': 3.76,
        'hammer': 1.28,
        'planes bag': 8.5
    },
    'pods bag': {
        'Pod': 1.74, 
        'optic': 0.86, 
        'pods bag': 8.72, 
        'thermal': 1.2
    }
}

ordered = OrderedDict(
    sorted(
        [[k,v] for (k,v) in x.items()], 
        key=lambda kv: sum(kv[1].values()), 
        reverse=True
    )
)

for item in ordered.values():
    print(sum(item.values()))
```

This will print your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is inherently unordered. So you would have to create the iteration order manually:

```
for _, dct in sorted(cls.bags.items()):
    pprint(sum(dct.values()))
```

Or sorted by the sum:

```
for s in sorted((sum(dct.values()) for dct in cls.bags.values()), reverse=True):
    pprint(s)
```

Comment: then I should maybe use an ordered dict, by still, I'll need to sort it by the sum of its nested dictionaries.
I Will edit the question.